# simulation of verilog in modelsim

Tags: verilog

my code for the design block and the testbench compiles, however when i simulate it in modelsim, i'm  getting this error: "Error loading design."
Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong in my code?

Here is the code for the design block::

```
module alu(c,carry,zero,a,b,cin,opr);    
input [3:0] a,b;         // port A,B     
input  cin ;             // carry input from carry flag register     
output [3:0] c;        // the result
output carry;    // carry output     
output zero ;   // zero output
input [3:0] opr ;        // functionality control for ALU     
wire [4:0] result;       // ALU result     
assign result = alu_out(a,b,cin,opr);     
assign c    = result[3:0];     
assign carry  = result[4] ;     
function [4:0] alu_out;       
input  [3:0] a,b ;      
input        cin ;       
input  [3:0] opr ;       
case ( opr )           
4'b0001: alu_out=a+4'b0001 ;         // increment data on port A

4'b0010: alu_out=a-4'b0001 ;         // decrement data on port A

4'b0011: alu_out=a+b+cin;            // ADD with CARRY

4'b0100: alu_out=a-b ;               // SUB without BORROW

4'b0101: alu_out=a-b+(~cin);         // SUB with BORROW

4'b0110: alu_out=a*b;

4'b0111: alu_out=a/b;

4'b1000: AND(alu_out, a, b);

4'b1001: OR(alu_out, a, b);

4'b1010: NAND(alu_out, a, b);        // NAND

4'b1011: NOR(alu_out, a, b); 

4'b1100: XNOR(alu_out, a, b);        

4'b1101: alu_out=a^b;                // EXOR

4'b1110: alu_out={b[3:0],1'b0};      // Shift Left

4'b1111: alu_out={b[0],1'b0,b[3:1]}; // Shift Right


default : begin

alu_out=9'bxxxxxxxxx;

$display("Invalid Operation!");

end    

endcase 

endfunction

endmodule
```

and here is the code for the testbench block:

```
module tb_alu();
    reg [3:0] _a, _b, _opr;
    reg  _cin;
    wire [3:0] _carry,  _zero,  _c;

    initial begin
    _a=4'b0001;
    _b=4'b0010;
    _cin=0;
    _opr=4'b0001;
    end
    alu al( _c, _carry, _zero,_a, _b, _cin, _opr);
endmodule
```

Comment: Why do your signal names begin with an underscore?  That just looks so strange to me...

Comment: under score is not a problem

Comment: I think `function` should have a begin before case, after inputs.

Comment: What error do you get? Usually before the sign "Error loading design." there is an information, what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers.
I used ISE for simulation and ISE didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

With minor modifications runs for me and outputs:

```
Invalid Operation!
Invalid Operation!
```

I removed the primitive gates and implied bitwise operations: Not sure on my XNOR though, you need to check it.

```
module test(c,carry,zero,a,b,cin,opr);    
input [3:0] a,b;         // port A,B     
input  cin ;             // carry input from carry flag register     
output [3:0] c;        // the result
output carry;    // carry output     
output zero ;   // zero output
input [3:0] opr ;        // functionality control for ALU     
wire [4:0] result;       // ALU result     
assign result = alu_out(a,b,cin,opr);     
assign c    = result[3:0];     
assign carry  = result[4] ;  

function [4:0] alu_out;       
  input  [3:0] a,b ;      
  input        cin ;       
  input  [3:0] opr ;  
  begin     
  case ( opr )           
    4'b0001: alu_out = a+4'b0001 ;         // increment data on port A
    4'b0010: alu_out = a-4'b0001 ;         // decrement data on port A
    4'b0011: alu_out = a+b+cin;            // ADD with CARRY
    4'b0100: alu_out = a-b ;               // SUB without BORROW
    4'b0101: alu_out = a-b+(~cin);         // SUB with BORROW
    4'b0110: alu_out = a*b;
    4'b0111: alu_out = a/b;
    4'b1000: alu_out = a&b; // AND(alu_out, a, b);
    4'b1001: alu_out = a|b; //OR(alu_out, a, b);
    4'b1010: alu_out = ~(a&b); //NAND(alu_out, a, b);        // NAND
    4'b1011: alu_out = ~(a|b); //NOR(alu_out, a, b); 
    4'b1100: alu_out = a~^b ; //XNOR(alu_out, a, b);        
    4'b1101: alu_out = a^b;                // EXOR
    4'b1110: alu_out = {b[3:0],1'b0};      // Shift Left
    4'b1111: alu_out = {b[0],1'b0,b[3:1]}; // Shift Right

    default : begin
      alu_out= 'x;
      $display("Invalid Operation!");
    end    

  endcase 
end

endfunction

endmodule
```

Comment: no! I used your code but i didn't see any changes in the error.

Comment: @user3197818, I have added the begin statement to the function. modelsim might require that syntax. let us know how the update example works.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the default statement as shown below:

```
  default : begin
  alu_out=5'bxxxxx;

  $display("Invalid Operation!");

end
```

This is because the function `alu_out`'s return value is of 5-bit size whereas in the default, it is a 9-bit size return value. This should get you rid of the error `Error loading design`.